# Errors in OracleReader results

Tags: c#, oracle, oracleclient

Ok, here's the problem:
When i use System.Data.OracleClient, all data returns as it should, and everything is ok, but since it's outdated API i tried to move to Oracle.DataAccess dll file.
And here comes the problem:
I do the request, but since i get data back it's all corrupted, shown as "?" chars in VS.
my connection string:

```
$"User Id={userCredits.DBLogin};Password={userCredits.DBPass};Persist Security Info=False;Data Source={server.Key}"
```

OracleCommand passes as it should without any errors, i didn't change it since changed DB driver.

Comment: Check [that](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/code-154692.html)

Comment: Didn't help at all.But thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't get why that happend, but after i reworked my code to use OracleDataAdapter instead of OracleDataReader, everything work just fine.